# Stratum from pool 0 detected new block

Tags: litecoin, cgminer, stratum

I'm trying to mine litecoin on [litecoin-pool](http://lite.coin-pool.com/) with cgminer

```
./cgminer --scrypt -u username.1 -p password -o stratum+tcp://lite.coin-pool.com:3333
```

and it keeps on returning

```
[2013-10-05 14:24:28] Stratum from pool 0 detected new block
[2013-10-05 14:25:16] Stratum from pool 0 detected new block
[2013-10-05 14:27:05] Stratum from pool 0 detected new block
[2013-10-05 14:27:22] Stratum from pool 0 detected new block
```

and I'm using the correct username and password.

What could be causing this?

Comment: What are you mining with? A cpu or gpu? If only a cpu and the pool has a share submission difficulty of 63 you might only submit a share every once in a while. As in every 15 minutes or so if you are using an older cpu. What is your hash rate?

Comment: Trying to mine bitcoin but all I get is this: Stratum from pool 0 detected new block (repeats numerous times)
Network diff set to 707M
New Block detected on network before longpoll
Stratum from pool 0 detected new block
(repeats numerous times) I didnt change any settings on CGMiner... running code I submitted was:
./cgminer -o stratum+tcp://us1.eclipsemc.com:3333 -O <username>:<password> Can you perhaps suggest anything?

Comment: I have the same problem. It keeps repeating that but it doesnt do anything else.It says my hash rate but doesnt mine anything. Im trying to mine bitcoin and im just testing my new ASIC out. It's only 11GHS

Comment: @Jojo: The Bitcoin hashrate is now 6 exahash/s. 11GH/s are 0.000000001833333 of the network's hashrate. It's probably not enough to register as work for the mining pool.

Answer (score 1):

It is not an error that new blocks are detected.
You should check other parts of the output to see if you are correctly connected, you are hashing and submitting shares.
If you want us to check what's wrong, please, submit some other part of the cgminer's log.

Answer (score 0):

That is a normal response - It's just letting the miner know that there's a new block to be working on. You should also be getting shares accepted, but that all depends opn your hashrate. Considering you're mining LTC, if your hashrate is low the shares you get could be pretty infrequent or nonexistent. What are you mining with and what is your hashrate?